# Laravel 8 | How to join two foreign keys on the same table

Tags: php, jquery, laravel, orm

Fields **'to_user_id'** and **'from_user_id'** are two id that are on the users table, since they have different values how to join my model 'Message' with the users table

```
   $my_inbox=Message::select('messages.*', 'users.name toUser', 'users.name as fromUser')
            ->join('users', 'users.id', '=', 'to_user_id.user_id')
            ->join('users', 'users.id', '=', 'from_user_id.user_id')
            ->get();
```

Comment: try the following:
->join('users as u1', 'u1.id', '=', 'to_user_id.user_id')
->join('users as u2' , 'u2.id', '=', 'from_user_id.user_id')

Comment: as @Abdel-azizhassan showed,  you need to set different aliases to join same table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use différent aliases to join same table. You see that selecting the same field is conflicting with what you want.

```
$my_inbox=Message::select('messages.*', 'receiver.name toUser', 'sender.name as fromUser')
            ->join('users as receiver', 'receiver.id', '=', 'to_user_id.user_id')
            ->join('users as sender', 'sender.id', '=', 'from_user_id.user_id')
            ->get();
```

Or if you had set the correct relation in the Message class and the user class

```
$my_inbox = $loggedUser->receivedMessages()->with('sender')->get();
```